# How much data can be loaded in a shiny app without causing stability issues?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Right now I'm loading roughly 100mb of data in the `global.R` file of a shiny app. While the app runs fine locally, Shiny Server regularly crashes. Often the culprit is the following error (after waiting about 30 seconds for the app to load):

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

The application took too long to respond.
```

I've tried every possible setting for `app_init_timeout`, including setting to -1 and still no luck.

I'm wondering if there is an upper bound to the amount of data that can be loaded in a Shiny Server session.

Here's what the shiny server config file looks like:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
 listen 3838;

# Define a location at the base URL
 location / {

# Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
site_dir /vagrant/sites/;

# Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

# When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
# an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
directory_index on;
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your shiny server config file?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `app_init_timeout`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to adjust the Shiny Server [`app_init_timeout`](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/#application-timeouts) parameter for your application:

> Each Shiny Application has two timeouts associated with it:
>
> app_init_timeout -- Describes the amount of time (in seconds) to wait
>   for an application to start. After this many seconds if the R process
>   still has not become responsive, it will be deemed an unsuccessful
>   startup and the connection will be closed.

You don't say what kind of infrastructure you are running it on, but if it is EC2, then you might want to get a bigger instance.

Comment: I've tried every possible setting for app_init_timeout, including setting to -1 and still no luck. I'll add that to my question for clarity.

Comment: @BenRollert In that case, you would need to post an MWE so that we can rule out something specific to your application.

Answer (score -2):

I Had the same problem.Try to release the permission of the folder where the shiny saves the file

Access the properties of the folder, select the option "set group, owner and permissions recursively" and put on the "Octal" 0777.

Comment: Although this might be a valid answer, you need to add more information on how to release the permissions